# Multiple Select - Render as url and search

Tags: product-attribute, multiselect-attribute, advanced-search

I'm building a bookshop with Magento. I've some multiple select custom attributes for Authors and Translators.

I'd like to render their values as a link to the advanced search to list all products for that Author / Translator.

- **First Problem**: The advanced search does not accept the string
  */catalogsearch/advanced/result/?author="Name"*
- **Second Problem**: Can I render every item as a Link? for eg. something like this

**< a href  =  "/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?author=  < ? php echo $_product->getAttributeText('author') ?>"> < ? php echo $_product->getAttributeText('author') ?>**

Comment: Hi domfitty, what have you tried and what doesn't work as expected? What you want to achieve sounds reasonable and shouldn't be any problem?

Comment: First problem is solved :) For single select attributes I'm able to get it as a link using this code <a href="/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?author=<?php echo $_product->getData('author') ?>"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('author') ?></a>
I'm not able to parse it if I select 2 or more options because I get an array. Any ideas?

Comment: what about `is_array` and `foreach`?

Comment: Maybe foreach is the solution... but I don't know hot :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is now with multiple select attributes. If you execute an advanced search and look at the resulting URL, you will see it looks like:

```
[YOUR_BASE_URL]/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?author[]=1&author[]=2&other_attribute[]=45
```

Actually, this is how you transfer multiple input values with the same name. The name is then not `name="author"`, but `name="author[]"`. Also, make sure you don't use `getAttributeText()` for the URL part - it expects the option_id, so `getData('author')` or the magic getter `getAuthor()` is correct.

Your final link would be like:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?author[]=<?php
    echo $_product->getAuthor() ?>"><?php
        echo $_product->getAttributeText('author') ?></a>
```

Now to the problem if a product has more than one author. As Fabian suggested, you can use is_array and foreach.

```
<?php

$_authors = $_product->getAuthor();
if( !is_array($_authors) ) {
    $_authors = explode(',', $_authors);
}
$_authorTexts = $_product->getAttributeText('author');
if( !is_array($_authorTexts) ) {
    $_authorTexts = array($_authorTexts);
}
foreach($_authors as $i => $_author) {
    ?><a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?author[]=<?php
        echo $_author ?>"><?php
            echo $_authorTexts[$i] ?></a><?php
}
```

Comment: You are quite right! I'm trying to use multiple select attributes in product detail and link them INDIVIDUALLY to advanced search page.
For example:
Book1 with Author1, Author2 --> 
   Link1 to advanced search of Author1 
AND 
   Link2 to advanced search of Author2

Comment: Okay, so why does my solution not work?

Comment: Because I'd like to have one <a tag for each author and not a unique tag for ALL authors.

Comment: Good start, but the code doesn't work :-(

Comment: Hm, sorry, but this is not helpful... what does not work? Is there an error? Is there any output? Could you maybe post the output of var_dump($_authors) and var_dump($_authorTexts) right after their definition?

Comment: Yes, sorry :-( The arrays are OK because the 2 dumps give the following values: array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "25,26" } array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "Bach" [1]=> string(13) "Mozart" } Tryed to edit the foreach clause with this code foreach($_authors as $i => $_author) {
            echo $_author[$i];
            echo $_authorTexts[$i];
} but it returns this string "2Bach"

Comment: I edited my answer to "$_authors = explode(',', $_authors);"; can you check again?

Comment: simonthesorcerer, It works great! Thank you!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) Please accept my answer to mark the question as solved - this is a beta site, and we need the statistics ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beta user.... how I can mark as solved?